# Where can the Coinbase referral link be found?

Tags: coinbase.com

I got the [coinbase bonus](https://www.criptomania.it/guide/coinbase-come-comprare-bitcoin-bonus/) signing up in an Italian site. I'm wondering if I can do the same promoting Coinbase to someone I know. I heard I can receive the bonus and they can get the bonus too. It sounds pretty good. But how can I have my link to give to my friends?

Comment: While we don't allow people to include referral links in their post on this site, I feel that this is a valid question about how to use Coinbase. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your profile settings you can get your referral link to invite your friends.
I think both of you will get $10 when your friend spends $100 in buys.